# Excel: Continuing numbering in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know that you can type 1,2,3,4, and the select and drag the 4 numbers and Excel will automatically start numbering them as far down as you drag.

**I was wondering if it would be possible for the numbers to stop at say 50, then continue from 51 in the next column?**

So column 1 would contain the numbers 1-50, column 2 51-100, column 3 101-150, column 4 151-200 and so on, each column containing the next 50 numbers.

Sort of like this:

```
Column1       Column2
1             51
2             52
3             53
4             54
5             55
6             56
7             57
```

Thanks

Comment: `I want to continue this on a couple more pages` - continue what? numbering increase/ or the same pattern? or.......? please be more clear, and better provide the sample.

Comment: What is your question? What's stopping you from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If '1' is in `A1`, put `=a1+50` in `B1` and drag to the right as far as required. Then select all the numbers in Row1 and drag the array down to Row50.